# Produce bounding box from contour locations

Tags: c, opencv

I am new to OpenCV so I apologize if I use incorrect terminology. I am writing a program in C that finds objects in an image (in this case red building blocks) and extracts that part of the image and displays it as a new image. I have thresholded the image to remove everything but red and used cvDilate to blur the results slightly to make the object more distinct. I then used the OpenCV Contour finding and drawing functions to locate and draw the blocks.

How can I access the contour locations stored as CvSeq* and take the upper-most and lower-most contour values from a cluster of contours (there may still be some noise from other red objects) so that I can make a bounding box around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have to do this manually because OpenCV provides this type of functionality for you.

Look at the [cvMinAreaRect2](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=cvmin#CvBox2D%20cvMinAreaRect2%28const%20CvArr%2a%20points,%20CvMemStorage%2a%20storage%29) and [cvBoundingRect](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=cvmin#boundingrect). Here are their examples respectively: [minarea.c](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/tags/2.3.1/opencv/samples/c/example_cmake/minarea.c) (has some debugging stuff, but should give you the gist of how to use it) and [generalContours_demo1.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/tags/2.3.1/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/ShapeDescriptors/generalContours_demo1.cpp) (in C++, but should be easy to translate).

As a side note, I would definitely suggest using the C++ API of OpenCV as it is a bit easier to understand and has more features. Also, you spend a lot less time/code worrying about memory management since the `Mat` class handles that for you.

Hope that helps!